# Bottom Navigation did not navigate when item is clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I created two activities as a navcontroller for the fragment, I am not sure if this is the right approach.

For `MyActivity`, the bottom navigation is working well and showing the fragment. But for the `MainActivityRelawan` the Home Menu didn't navigate when item is clicked and the fragment only is shown after I press back button, I don't know why.

The `main_activity` is for controlling the Main Activity Fragment, and `main_activity_relawan` is for controlling Main Activity Relawan Fragment.

This is my `MainActivityRelawan`

```
 val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main_relawan)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home_relawan, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

And this is my `MainActivity`

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

and for each of `findNavController` i use different activity XML and different `navGraph`
this is my `MainActivity findNavController`

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

and this is my `MainActivityRelawan NavController`

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_relawan"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main_relawan"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view_relawan"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_relawan" />
```

and i using different navGraph for each. This is `NavigationGraph` for `MainActivity`

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.example.tes.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.example.tes.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:name="com.example.tes.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_notifications"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notifications" />
```

and this is `NavGraph` for the `MainActivityRelawan`

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_relawan"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home_relawan">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home_relawan"
        android:name="com.example.tes.ui.home_relawan.RelawanFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_relawan" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_home_relawan_to_navigation_dashboard"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_dashboard" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.example.tes.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_dashboard_to_navigation_notifications"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_notifications" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:name="com.example.tes.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_notifications"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notifications" >

    </fragment>



</navigation>
```

Comment: You can control fragments using NavController and not activity. I am not sure what is your use case, but if you want to have multiple screens and navigate using bottom navigation then you should ONE single Activity and make it as your fragment container and then using Navigation resource layout create a navigation graph for navigating between different fragments in the same Activity using that container.

Comment: uplaod res menu file buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved, this is happened just because i made different id for the menu bottom navigation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I used it in one Activity. I doun't know it's good or not. So you can see solution in my [git](https://github.com/Gizcerbes/androidJun/tree/double_navigation)